# getaddrinfo and gethostbyname hangs the system

Tags: dns, real-time, nslookup, ecos

I am working on an [eCos](http://ecos.sourceware.org) project and I have a big problem. For some reason [getaddrinfo](http://ecos.sourceware.org/docs-3.0/ref/net-common-tcpip-manpages-getaddrinfo.html) and [gethostbyname](http://ecos.sourceware.org/docs-3.0/ref/net-common-tcpip-manpages-gethostbyname.html) seem to hang the whole system from time to time in the production environment.

I have read that this is also an issue in linux if the DNS does not answer. To remedy the problem in Linux there is another function created called [getaddrinfo_a](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo_a.3.html).

Now I am looking for a failsafe solution to do DNS lookups in eCos, at least I don't want to hang the whole system. Is there any or do I need to be 100% sure that my DNS will deliver ip addresses and if not I will end up with a hanged system?

I have thought about making my own DNS implementation but that feels a bit too drastic. I have also thought about using some external library, but in that case I need one that works with eCos and that have a license I can use in a commercial project.

Comment: If available, consider getaddrinfo_a().